# How come is my array not reactive in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

Good evening everyone,

I have been making a kind of social network as a personal project using vuejs, nodejs and mysql database.

Basically, you can post a message, and then people can answer to it. I bind comments to post using an id. I got two tables: 1 comments and 1 posts. If a comment is posted for post number 38, in mysql table there is a field idPost = 38.

i got a function displaying all the answers for the post by clicking on a button, which is:

```js
    displayAnswers(id) {
                axios.get('http://localhost:3000/wall/answer/get/'+id )
                .then(response => {
                    this.answers = response.data.resultat;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
```

Where id is the id of the post I want to display answers.

Now, the problem is when I add a comment, I need either to refresh the page to see the comment or to force the refresh by calling the displaypost function, like this:

```js
    postAnswer(id) {
                let syntaxe = /^[a-z A-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0-9-]{1,}$/;
                if(syntaxe.test(this.answerToPost)) {
                    let answer = {
                        message: this.answerToPost,
                        postId: id,
                        auteur: this.$store.state.pseudoUser
                    }
                    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/wall/post/answer', answer)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.feedbackMessage = response.data.message;
                        this.isAlert = false; 
                        this.answerToPost = '';
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.feedbackMessage = ''
                        }, 2000);
                        this.displayAnswers(id);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.feedbackMessage = error.response.data.message; 
                        this.isAlert = true; 
                    })
                } else {
                    this.errorMessage = "Le message ne respecte pas la syntaxe autorisée";
                    return;
                }
            },
```

To summarize, my data this.answers, is not reactive. it is declared this way in the app:

```js
    data() {
            return {
                Auteur: '',
                displayPostAnswers: [],
                answerToPost: '',
                isAlert: true,
                feedbackMessage: '',
                answers: ''
            }
        },
```

and called this way in my template, using a `v-for` loop to display the answers:

```html
    <div v-for="answer in answers" :key="answer.id" class="answerDisplayer" > 
                <div class="containerEachAnswer">
                    <div class="avatarAuteur">
                        <img src="../assets/defaultUser.png" width="48" height="48" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="answer">
                    <span>
                    <strong>{{ answer.auteur }}</strong><br>
                    {{ answer.message}}
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I looked for the issue on the internet, I found this doc: https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html.
So I tried to use the function `Vue.set` but it does not seem to work.

I would like to know if more experienced developer could help me to find another way to either make my data reactive or help me to do it another way, I tried several kind of things but it did not work.

PS: I tried to use computed data, but `v-for` does not work with computed data.

Thank you!

Have a good evening!

Comment: You initialize `answers: ''` with an empty string. Sure this is the correct data structure to use for `v-for`?

Comment: Well i think so ? How do you think i should initialize it ?

Comment: I did it, it's the PostAnswer function ;)

Comment: Hmm but besides in the axios callback when calling the `displayAnswers` function I think you are not actually making any change to `this.answers` after posting the answer. I mean, it should work if you make any change to the `answers` property besides the ones from this [article](https://medium.com/@miladmeidanshahi/update-array-and-object-in-vuejs-a283983fe5ba).

Comment: Also I think you meant `displayAnswers` when you wrote "displaypost", right?

Comment: Yes but since i am adding a new answer in my database it should update answers right ? When i post an answer the function displayanswers has been called once already

Comment: If it's an array, init it with `answers: []`, not `answers: ''`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to change this within the instance I suggest you try `this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)` as described in https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Pour-les-objects

Also you seem to declare `answers` as a string in your `data` function, try declaring it as an array `answers: []`